Nginx Timeouts getting status code 502 when using Gunicorn
AM currently having an issue here. My Django application is timing out i.e 502 when i place it behind a proxy like nginx. I have tried to increase the timeouts but still not thing has change any help will be highly appreciated. Am using gunicorn as my production server. Any help will be highly appreciated.
"""


For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.43.78', 'localhost'] 

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://192.168.43.78:8094']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'tickets',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'notifications',
    'widget_tweaks'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'tickets.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'tickets.middleware.UserDashboardMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ticket_resolution.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ticket_resolution.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ['NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['POSTGRES_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['DB_HOST'],
        'PORT': int(os.environ['DB_PORT']),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'EAT'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Kampala' 


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/' 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')  

# Media files (user-uploaded files)
# Define the directory where media files will be uploaded
# Define the URL prefix to serve media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'  
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tickets/static/ticket_images')  
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/tickets/dashboard/'
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

# Celery configuration
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://redis:6379/0'

# Email settings
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = os.environ['EMAIL_HOST']
EMAIL_PORT = int(os.environ['EMAIL_PORT'])
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ['EMAIL_HOST_USER']
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''

SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 31536000  # 1 year
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True



Docker-compose file

version: '2'

services:
 # Nginx server
 nginx:
   # Build context
   build: ./nginx
  
   # Mapping machine and container ports
   ports:
     - 8094:443
    
   # Storage volumes
   volumes:
     - static_volume:/home/app/static
     - media_volume:/home/app/media
     - ./ssl:/ssl
   depends_on:
     - web

   networks:
     - app_network

   restart: "on-failure"

 web:
   container_name: django_app
   build: .
   command: sh -c "gunicorn ticket_resolution.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --keyfile=/ssl/my.key --certfile=/ssl/my.crt --timeout 200 --log-level debug --workers 4"
   volumes:
     - .:/code
     - ./ssl:/ssl   # Mounting the directory containing SSL certificates
     - static_volume:/home/app/static
     - media_volume:/home/app/media
   env_file:
     - .env
   depends_on:
     - db
     - redis
   networks:
     - app_network
   restart: "on-failure"

 redis:
   container_name: redis
   image: redis:latest
   ports:
     - "6379:6379"
   networks:
     - app_network

 db:
   container_name: db
   image: postgres:latest
   volumes:
     - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
   env_file:
     - .env
   networks:
     - app_network

networks:
 app_network:
   driver: bridge

volumes:
 postgres_data:
 static_volume:
 media_volume:



Nginx config

upstream django_app {
    server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /ssl/my.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl/my.key;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/app/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://django_app;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        # Add the X-CSRFToken header
        proxy_set_header X-CSRFToken $http_csrf_token;

        proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
    }
}

